# mvc OperationContract not generate with ServiceKnownType

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, code-generation

something strange happen when i use mvc4 projcet and add service reference
the knowntypes attribute is not generate like it does in my asp.net projects.

this generate code from mvc:

```
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ILookUpService/GetSystems", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ILookUpService/GetSystemsResponse")]
    BG.ServiceResult GetSystems();
```

and this one from my asp.net:

```
        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/ILookUpService/GetSystems", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/ILookUpService/GetSystemsResponse")]
 [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(Jo.joServices.BillingSystems))]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceKnownTypeAttribute(typeof(Jo.joServices.BillingSubsystems[]))]


    BG.ServiceResult GetSystems();
```

the problem in the mvc is that i get an error of deserialzie

Comment: What kind of properties does billingsystems & billingSubsystem have? Could be some property isn't serializable

Comment: there is difference between asp.net and mvc with serialize?